# Using a custom join with summing in ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I haven't found any example that allows for something like the following...

```
select
    o.*,
    total.OrderTotal
from Orders o
join
    (select OrderId,sum(ProductCost) as OrderTotal from OrderItems group by OrderId) total on o.OrderId=total.OrderId
```

I was able to get around it by putting the sum into a custom select column, but that avenue failed once I wanted to add the ability to filter the results by OrderTotal which can be done in the above by adding a `having sum(ProductCost)>??`.

Is this possible without doing straight custom SQL?

Comment: Not possible if you want to keep it in 1 query, i.e. you'd need to use the above custom SQL with `Select` or `SqlList` and a Custom POCO that has an `OrderTotal` field.